# Trouble with using default export from btoa library in compiled commonjs code

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, babeljs, commonjs

I am working on a Typescript project which makes use of the [btoa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/btoa) library.

I import it into my TS like so:

```
import btoa from 'btoa';
```

and use it accordingly:

```
xhr.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Basic ${btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(`${user}:${pass}`)))}`;
```

I am compiling my TS down to commonjs in ES5 format using tsc, webpack with babel-loader plugin, and when I attempt to use my lib in a node environment, I get an error at the point the btoa function is attempted to be invoked:

```
TypeError: btoa_1.default is not a function
```

The btoa package does have a typings file, where it exports a default function:

```
export default function(str: string): string;
```

I can only guess the way I am importing this could be wrong?

My tsconfig is as follows in case it's relevant:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "outDir": "./dist/commonjs",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declarationDir": "./dist/typings/",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],

  },
  "files": [
    "./src/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

What do I need to do to allow the btoa package to be used correctly in my compiled commonjs code?

Thanks

**Update**

I tried using the following syntax:

```
import * as btoa from 'btoa';
```

After which the TS complains at the point I try to use it, saying:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("/Users/rparker-admin/Documents/Github/nepal/api-client/node_modules/@types/btoa/index")' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I then realised I could invoke `btoa.default(...)` in my TS source file, and that resolves the TS error, but I still have a problem in my compiled commonjs code:

```
TypeError: btoa.default is not a function
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

according to [import mosdules in typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) if you want to import an entire module you should use: `import * as [name] from 'btoa'`

Comment: Thanks, I did try this before, I should have said on my original question, see my updated questiion

Comment: i've installed btoa and tried to import it as i did above. when i used it, it work fine for me. can you please write an example how did you try to use it? thanks.

Comment: I believe this is down to how babel (which I am using with webpack) is compiling down to es5 for me and how it treats the default export in the btoa package.

Answer (score 0):

So I got past my issue using the `esModuleInterop` flag in my tsconfig and setting this to true. I came across this setting when searching across other posts and found that it replicates some behaviour in Babel which I was using with my webpack config but I dont think I had it configured correctly in the first place.

Anyway I have now been able to not use Babel at all and just get the TS compiler to compile down to commonjs in es5 format and also generate a UMD build using webpack.

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "outDir": "./dist/commonjs",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist/typings/",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],

  },
  "files": [
    "./src/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env) => {

  return {
    entry: {
      'index': path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/commonjs/index.js')
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/umd'),
      filename: '[name].js',
      library: 'subscriptionsClient',
      libraryTarget: 'umd', // supports commonjs, amd and web browsers
      globalObject: 'this'
    }
  };

};
```

In my package.json I set the following entries:

```
"main": "./dist/umd/index.js",
"module": "./dist/commonjs/index.js",
"types": "./dist/typings/index.d.ts",
```

I am now able to consume my built library sources in Angular (webpack) and in node.

Hopefully this may help others out there.